# can't get value from email field by jquery val() function if email id given

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I am developing a codeigniter application. My problem is when I give email id in html5 email input it can't be accessed by jquery `val()` function but when I give any other value other than email id format it is could be accessed.
It is my html,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
                Personal Cash Book
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/CSS/login.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>


                    <div class="bg login">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">
                                    <div class="page-header">
                                        <h3>
                                            <b>
                                                Personal Cash Book
                                            </b>
                                        </h3>


                                    </div>

                                        <form>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="username">
                                                USERNAME
                                            </label>
                                            <input type="email" id="username" name="email" class="form-control"  required >
                                        </div>


                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <button type="button" id="sub" class="btn btn-danger">
                                                Submit
                                            </button>


                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                        <h3>
                                            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message');?>
                                        </h3>



                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="container footer-section">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <footer >
                        All rights reserved.Created By&nbsp; <a href="http://www.christalinfotech.com" class="author" target="_blank"> Bibin Paul.P</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; Licenced to Sido Antony
                    </footer>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function()
                        {
                            $(document).on('click','#sub',function()
                            {
                                var email=$('#username').val();
                                $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>master/reset-password/'+email+'/',function(data)
                                    {
                                        alert(data);
                                    }
                                );
                            })
                        })
                    </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

It is my controller,

```
<?php

class Master extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('encryption');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','USERNAME','xss_clean|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','PASSWORD','xss_clean|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('','');
        if($this->form_validation->run()===FALSE)
        {
            if(form_error('email'))
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message',form_error('email'));
            }

            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message',form_error('password'));
            }

            $this->load->view('login');
        }

        else
        {
            $email=$this->input->post('email');
            $password=$this->input->post('password');

            $data=$this->common->login($email,$password);
            if($data)
            {
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_data',$data);
                redirect('/dashboard');
            }

            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Incorrect credentials');
                redirect('/');
            }

        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('user_data');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message','You are logged out successfully');
        redirect('/');
    }

    public function forget_password()
    {
        $this->load->view('forget_password');
    }

    public function reset_password($email)
    {
        echo "password reset".$email;
    }
, 

?>
```

Purpose is I want to check username exists or not I used a *jquery* script for implement it as ajax function not supported in ***codeigniter*** when csrf protection enabled. I use html5 email input field for enter username it's id is username. I could get response from server side when I give a value other than email id, but when I give email id no response getting. It is my problem

Answer (score 0):

is it possible this line is interfering with the id="username" ?

```
<label class="form-label" for="username">
```

not sure if jquery is picking up the first instance of username which wouldn't have a value

Answer (score 0):

Here is your script tested and working fine:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click','#sub', function() {
            var email = $('#username').val();
            $.get('<?php echo base_url('welcome');?>/test?email='+email, function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Nothing else was changed and it is getting the value of the email correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution after 3 hours of searching...

In your form:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<label class="check-text" for="username">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<label class="check-text" for="email">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>
```

Then load the jQuery form validation:

`<script src="path/js/jquery.validate.min.js") ?>"></script>`

Then validate as follow:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("form[name='register']").validate({
    // Validation rules
    rules: {
      username: {
    required: true,
    remote: {
     url: '<?php echo site_url("account/check_username") ?>',
     type: "post",
     cache: false,
     // data: {
     //  username: function(){
     //   return $("#username").val();
     //  }
     // }
    }
   },
      email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    remote: {
     url: '<?php echo site_url("account/check_email") ?>',
     type: "post",
     cache: false,
     // data: {
     //  email: function(){
     //   return $("#email").val();
     //  }
     // }
    }
   }
  },
  // Validation error messages
  messages: {
   username: {
    required: '&#9888; The username is required.',
    remote: '&#9888; This username is already registered.'
   },
   email: {
    required: '&#9888; The email is required.',
    remote: '&#9888; This email is already registered.'
   }
  },
  // Make sure the form is submitted
  submitHandler: function(form) {
  form.submit();
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

In the controller:

```
  public function check_username(){
      $this->layout = 'ajax';

  if ($this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'))->get('users')->row()){
   echo json_encode(FALSE);
  }else{
   echo json_encode(TRUE);
        }
    }

 public function check_email(){
        $this->layout = 'ajax';

  if ($this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'))->get('users')->row()){
   echo json_encode(FALSE);
  }else{
   echo json_encode(TRUE);
        }
    }
```

And here is the final results:
[image]

Hope it can help you or someone }else{.

Thanks